# Explanation of edit rejection for Python slicing answer

Tags: discussion

Can anyone explain why 3 of 4 reviewers rejected [this Python edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1858203)?  The edit is correct and I believe the additional example adds value by making the answer more complete.  Adding the example as a separate answer is less valuable since it is so closely related to an existing answer.

Comment: It would have probably better to add a comment, for the author to add it. Because if you ever insert some code that does not work, the author of the post gets blamed, while it's not his fault. If you put it in a comment and the author add it, then he gets blamed for stuff HE did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggested edits exist to make the existing content of the author better, not to add new content (unless the post is Community Wiki, in which case changing the content of the answer is acceptable).  The reviewers (correctly in my mind) felt that your edit was adding entirely new content, which is not what the edit system is in place for.

Comment: Thank you, that is not so clearly explained in the edit process.

Comment: @dansalmo See the relevant FAQ page on the subject: [how do suggested edits work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)